# Himalayan Succulent Identification

Tags: identification, succulents, transplanting

On my recent trip to the Lower Himalayas, I came across this succulent in the crevices of the rock. I have taken the plant back home and planted this in a pot having coco peat and compost. I have two questions

1. Could someone identify this succulent for me
2. Will this succulent survive hot climate (approx 40 degree Celsius)

[image: Himalayan Succulent]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is some sort of Sempervivum (or maybe Sedum). The size tell me more Sedum, but the leaves are much more of Semprevivum.

These are are plants which survive in extreme climate: dry (not much liquid water), and with strong sun (mountains have less atmosphere to block UV).

So I think you could growth them on hot climate.